# How can We find no of fixed hard disk in system excluding removable disk if any

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

How can We find no of fixed hard disk in system excluding removable disk if any.
I used Msinfo32 and diskpart and found problem with both.
Diskpart detects removable disk as a fixed disk while Msinfo32 takes too much time on windows xp to execute.
below are the two commands which i was using with MSinfo32 and diskpart.
**diskpart list disk
"%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\MSInfo\MSINFO32.EXE" /report disks_output.txt /categories +component**

Any help in this regard would be very helpful to us.
Thanks.

Comment: Double Click on "My Computer" Icon and you found the solution :-) (Kidding)

Answer (score 1):

With Powershell using WMI:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk" | ? { $_.driveType -eq 3 }
```

If you need just the number of fixed disk:

```
 @(Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk" | ? { $_.driveType -eq 3 }).count
```

Answer (score 0):

The DriveType property (numeric), corresponds to the type of disk drive the logical disk represents.
Value of 3 represent Local Disk. Use the Filter parameter to get just local disks.
Add the ComputerName parameter to get the result from remote computers

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3"
```

Add the ComputerName parameter to get the result from remote computers

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType=3" -ComputerName pc1,pc2
```